# Programmatically specifying the column names within functions in the data table

Tags: r, data.table, n-gram, corpus

This continues from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371124/speeding-up-the-processing-of-large-data-frames-in-r) that I asked the other day (I now think I should've asked this at the same time).

## Data

`token.dt` is a list consisting of data tables each of which corresponds to the *n* in *n*-grams and includes the *n*-grams (i.e., *n* sequence of words) and their scores.

```
> head(token.dt[[2]])
   V1  V2       mi2
1:  0   0  6.494179
2:  0 001 13.249067
3:  0 002 13.249067
4:  0 005 13.249067
5:  0 025 13.249067
6:  0 039 13.249067

> head(token.dt[[5]])
   V1  V2 V3       V4    V5       mi5
1:  0   0  1        0     1 10.353265
2:  0 001 in    apart   for  6.807743
3:  0 001 in    thick   and  5.190449
4:  0 002 on     each  side 11.688710
5:  0 005  m       in     f  9.940322
6:  0 025 in aluminum which  8.249075
```

## Task

The task is to select the *n*-grams (i.e., rows of the tables in `token.dt`) that satisfy the following condition. The algorithm retains the *n*-gram only if its score is higher than the scores of the *n-1* grams and the *n+1* grams identified by the following way:

- the *n-1* grams that match the first *n-1* words of the *n*-gram and
- the *n+1* grams whose first n words match the *n*-gram.

By way of example, consider the following.

```
> for (i in 2:n) setkeyv(token.dt[[i]], paste0("V", 1:i))
> token.dt[[2]][J("0", "1")]
   V1 V2      mi2
1:  0  1 7.135725

> token.dt[[3]][J("0", "1")]
   V1 V2        V3       mi3
1:  0  1         0  9.803035
2:  0  1         2  6.809646
3:  0  1         f  6.142258
4:  0  1         m  7.315181
5:  0  1 milligram 13.517241
6:  0  1        mv 13.517241
7:  0  1        of  1.151899
8:  0  1       the  0.214648
9:  0  1        to  3.633922

> token.dt[[4]][J("0", "1")]
    V1 V2        V3      V4       mi4
 1:  0  1         0       1 10.507784
 2:  0  1         2       3 11.541023
 3:  0  1         f     the  3.927859
 4:  0  1         m neutral 13.621798
 5:  0  1 milligram      of  3.852570
 6:  0  1 milligram     per 10.638304
 7:  0  1        mv       m 11.260860
 8:  0  1        of  making 12.235372
 9:  0  1       the  number  9.707556
10:  0  1        to       0 12.669723
11:  0  1        to       5 11.158356
```

Here, the trigram (sequence of three words) *0 1 0* is not retained because although the bigram that shares the first two words (*0 1*) has a lower score (9.803035 > 7.135725), the 4-gram whose first three words match the trigram (*0 1 0 1*) has a higher score than the trigram in concern (10.507784 > 9.803035).

The trigram *0 1 milligram* is retained because its score is higher than the bigram that shares the first two words (13.517241 > 7.135725) and the two 4-grams whose first three words match the trigram (13.517241 > 3.852570, 13.517241 > 10.638304).

The task above is achieved non-programmatically in the following way.

```
> z <- token.dt[[4]][token.dt[[3]][token.dt[[2]], allow.cartesian = TRUE], list(k = all(mi3 > max(mi2, mi4)), mi3), allow.cartesian = TRUE][(k)]
> head(z)
   V1 V2        V3    k      mi3
1:  0  1 milligram TRUE 13.51724
2:  0  1        mv TRUE 13.51724
3:  0 15         g TRUE 12.24260
4:  0  2      gram TRUE 13.52079
5:  0  2     mrads TRUE 13.34449
6:  0  3        wt TRUE 13.28771
```

What I would like to know is how to do the above programmatically, that is, without hard-coding column names (e.g., mi3, mi4, etc.).

## Failed Attempts

Simply creating character strings with the `paste0` function and adding the argument of `with = FALSE` does not seem to work.

```
> i <- 3
> z <- token.dt[[i + 1]][token.dt[[i]][token.dt[[i - 1]], allow.cartesian = TRUE], list(k = all(paste0("mi", i) > max(paste0("mi", i - 1), paste0("mi", i + 1))), paste0("mi", i)), with = FALSE, allow.cartesian = TRUE][(k)]
Error in abs(j) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

Trying to evaluate the character strings above on the spot leads to the failure to find the columns. Adding `envir = .SD` to `eval`s below led to the same error as below.

```
> z <- token.dt[[i + 1]][token.dt[[i]][token.dt[[i - 1]], allow.cartesian = TRUE], list(k = all(eval(parse(text = paste0("mi", i))) > max(eval(parse(text = paste0("mi", i - 1))), eval(parse(text = paste0("mi", i + 1))))), eval(parse(text = paste0("mi", i)))), allow.cartesian = TRUE][(k)]
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'mi3' not found
```

The only way that works so far is by first concatenating necessary data tables and then following the same way above.

```
> for (j in 2:4) {
+   if (j == 2) {
+     all <- copy(token.dt[[j]])
+   } else {
+     all <- token.dt[[j]][all, allow.cartesian = TRUE]
+   }
+ }

> head(all)
   V1  V2 V3       V4       mi4       mi3       mi2
1:  0   0  1        0 13.292479  9.766820  6.494179
2:  0 001 in    apart 13.233742  5.624795 13.249067
3:  0 001 in    thick 13.005608  5.624795 13.249067
4:  0 002 on     each 10.416711  7.301489 13.249067
5:  0 005  m       in  5.625874 11.205271 13.249067
6:  0 025 in aluminum 13.443647  5.624795 13.249067

> z <- all[1:1000 , list(k = all(eval(parse(text = paste0("mi", i)), envir = .SD) > max(eval(parse(text = paste0("mi", i - 1)), envir = .SD), eval(parse(text = paste0("mi", i + 1)), envir = .SD))), mi = eval(parse(text = paste0("mi", i)), envir = .SD)), by = c(paste0("V", 1:i))][(k)]
> z <- unique(z)
> head(z)
   V1 V2        V3    k       mi
1:  0  1 milligram TRUE 13.51724
2:  0  1        mv TRUE 13.51724
3:  0 15         g TRUE 12.24260
4:  0  2      gram TRUE 13.52079
5:  0  2     mrads TRUE 13.34449
6:  0  3        wt TRUE 13.28771
```

However, this is unacceptably slow. Processing 1,000 rows (above) out of 970,696 rows takes more than five seconds. Given that the corpus I'm using here is much smaller than the corpus I want to apply the algorithm to, I am seeking ways to speed up the process.

## Reproducible Example

The simulated data set below should work to illustrate the point.

```
token.dt <- list()
types <- combn(LETTERS, 3, paste, collapse = "")
set.seed(1)
data <- data.table(matrix(sample(types, 4 * 1E6, replace = TRUE), ncol = 4))
setkey(data, V1, V2, V3, V4)
set.seed(1)
for (n in 2:4) {
    token.dt[[n]] <- unique(cbind(data[ , 1:n, with = FALSE]))
    token.dt[[n]][ , paste0("mi", n) := runif(nrow(token.dt[[n]])) * 10]
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You may want to focus this just down to your reproducible example and put the rest of your actual problem in a Gist.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have just cut it down to a some degree, though it's still a bit long. I tried to shorten it before posting, but wasn't quite sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the `eval` approach to work, you have to build the whole expression first, and then `eval`.  I ran this on a reduced version of your sample (40 values instead of 4e6):

```
i <- 3
x <- parse(
  text=paste0(
    "list(k = all(mi", i, " > max(mi", i - 1, 
    ", mi", i + 1, ")), mi", i, ")"
) )  
token.dt[[i + 1]][
  token.dt[[i]][token.dt[[i - 1]], allow.cartesian = TRUE], 
  eval(x),
  allow.cartesian = TRUE
][(k)]
#     V1  V2  V3    k      mi3
# 1: CIX BQV OWY TRUE 6.870228
# 2: GIU IJM HMO TRUE 7.698414
# 3: NQR FHN DOY TRUE 9.919061
# 4: PSX IPQ ACN TRUE 7.774452
```

As you can see, programatically referring to columns works.  This ran in about 3 seconds on my system with your full data set (4MM values).

Comment: Might try to use bquote to make that a bit more readable; just a suggestion.

Comment: @ClaytonStanley, while I hadn't though of this (and at first was, oh Duh!), the nature of the problem is such that I think you have to resort to things like: `bquote(.(as.name(paste0("m", i))) > .(as.name(paste0("m", i + 1))`, which I'm not sure are any clearer.  If you have a better way let me know.